# Python code wont input "User_name and Pass_word to mysql

Tags: python-3.x

I have tried multiple times to get user name and password from the inputs and then  save them into mysql. But it either does not print to mysql or gives out an error. I got exhausted  of all my methods that I tied.

````py
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="root",
  passwd="",
  database = "empty for a reason"
)
mycursor = mydb.cursor()

user_name = str(input("Please Enter a UserName: "))

pass_word = str(input("Please enter a PassWord: "))

sql = "INSERT INTO users (user_name.str()), pass_word.str()) VALUES (%s, %s)"


mycursor.execute(sql, (user_name.str, pass_word.str))

time.sleep(5)


#sql = "INSERT INTO users (" + str(user_name) + "," + str(pass_word) +") VALUES (%s, %s)"```

'str' object has no attribute 'str'
line 20, in <module>
    mycursor.execute(sql, (user_name.str, pass_word.str))  is the error the current code above is giving.
````

Comment: Is your issue capturing the user input as a string, or using their inputs to connect to the database? I don't understand what your problem is.

Comment: using the input, to go into the database. EX: Enter a password, *user inputs password "123"* 
on the database, i want it to store "123" in a user category, as well as there username

Comment: What you are saying still doesn't make sense. do you need to: ENTER the database, or STORE the values in the database, or BOTH?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

user_name and pass_word are both already strings from where you read in the user input. Thus, there is no need to cast it to a string again.

However, if you would like to cast an object to a string in Python use the "str()" method. Here is a link for examples: 
https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_casting.asp

So you should be able to use this line and have the code execute:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO users (user_name, pass_word) VALUES (%s, %s)"  
mycursor.execute(sql, (user_name, pass_word))
```

Comment: When i run what you posted i get a separate error. If you haven't guessed yet, Im a noob to python. Heres my error ```python                                                                
 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '()), pass_word()) VALUES ('gabe', '3232')' at line 1```

Comment: That error relates to your sql query, not the Python, so this answer solves your initial question

Answer (score 0):

Ii had to deal with this issue just now, and I found that as soon as you use
`mysql.connector.connect`, it wants to connect in this very second (logical if you think about it), meaning it needs to have everything as you execute this command. You need to take the user input before if you want this to work.